# Sqlite Electron: Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: node.js, angular, sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to open an sqlite database file using node-sqlite3 in my Angular + Electron app.

Despite I made sure that the file exists and Electron can read it, when I try to create the sqlite database using:

```
import * as sqlite from 'sqlite3';

// ...

const path = `${__dirname}/assets/sqlite.db`;

const fs = require('electron').remote.require('fs');
console.log(path);
if (fs.existsSync(AppConfig.sqlitePath)) {
  console.log('the file exists');
} else {
  console.log('the file does not not');
}

const myDb = new sqlite.Database(path, sqlite.OPEN_READONLY, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The file exists, since I got the right `console.log` message and it looks like:

```
/tmp/.mount_xxxxxx/resources/app.asar.unpacked/dist/assets/sqlite.db
```

However, from `new sqlite.Database(...)` I get the following error, as the file didn't exist:

> Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Comment: May I asked why did you put the database inside assets folder?

Comment: @HoangTranSon just because I wanted it to be included in the `dist` directory on app build. I know I could just use a different path by adding a new entry in my `angular.json` file, but I just wanted to have a working prototype quickly and the `assets` folder is being included by default.

Comment: May I asked how can you control security problem when you put that file in `assets` folder? I am facing same issue with react and the workaround now is put the db file into `public` folder. It looks like not a good way.

Comment: @HoangTranSon Sorry, I don't have any security concerns as my sqlite DB does not contain any sensitive data at all and it's already public

Answer (score 5):

I was tipped by [artiebits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5652719/artiebits) to look at [asarUnpack](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#configuration-asarUnpack) and indeed that was the right way to go.

---

I solved by:

1) adding the following to my `electron-builder.json`:

```
"asarUnpack": [
  "dist/assets/sqlite.db"
],
```

2) replacing:

```
const path = `${__dirname}/assets/sqlite.db`;
```

with:

```
const path = `${__dirname}/assets/sqlite.db`.replace('app.asar', 'app.asar.unpacked');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the absolute address of the database file**

***Example:***

Linux:

```
const path = "/home/brunodev/Documents/vscode/Git/backend/src/database/database.db"
```

Windows:

```
const path = "C:/Users/brunodev/Documents/vscode/Git/backend/src/database/database.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here using the extraResources parameter: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4644#issuecomment-637030403

```
# packages.json
"build": {
    ...
    "extraResources": [
      "databaseFolder"
    ],
   ...
}
```

Make sure to check if the database file exists then sync

```
const path = require('path');
const fse = require('fs-extra')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbPath = path.resolve(process.resourcesPath, 'databaseFolder')
const dbFile = path.resolve(dbPath, 'database.sqlite')

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: dbFile
})

if (!fse.existsSync(dbPath)) {
  fse.ensureDirSync(dbPath)
  fse.ensureFileSync(dbFile)
  sequelize.sync({ force: true })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following approach:

```
const path = require("path");
const dbPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "database");
```

Note:
If your db is placed at the root directory then only the below code will work without using __dirname.

```
const dbPath = path.resolve("database");
```