# Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file with electron-forge packed app

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron

I'm using a sqlite database called `sqlite.db` in my app.
The database is located in the top directory of my app.

I test the app with `npm start` while developing. While testing, the database works fine.

After creating the app via `npm run make` (electron-forge), the database cannot be accessed with the following error: `SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file with electron-forge`.

- My first thought was a wrong directory in the code, but that doesn't seem to be the issue after all.
- Also the database itself is available in the packed application.
- And it doesn't seem to be a code issue as texting works fine:

```
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
    const { open } = require('sqlite');
    sqlite3.verbose();
    return open({
        filename,                    //filename='./sqlite.db' (actually a path)
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    });
```

This brings me to the conclusion, something must be wrong in the configuration for the app-building process via Electron Forge. But I have no clue if that assumption is correct - and if so, how to do that.

The closest I found to a fix was [this similar issue but with Electron Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60422885/sqlite-electron-error-sqlite-cantopen-unable-to-open-database-file) - since I use Electron Forge, I wasn't able to apply the suggested solution 1:1...